# IE.LocationURL only returns part value

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm hoping you can help as I have exhausted everything that I know to try. Basically I have a VBA macro that does some automation on internet explorer to get some reports off one of our internal sites using SendKeys and within this macro I am also trying to copy the URL of the website so that I can make a hyperlink in my spreadsheet. Now at first I was using SendKeys to navigate to the address bar and using `SendKeys "^c", True` to copy it and then paste it in my spreadsheet but I have decided that I want to run the automation in full screen mode so that I can ignore the address bar and the favourites bar when tabing through the website. However when running full screen mode I cant navigate to the address bar so I decided to use `IE.LocationURL` to get me the URL of the page, but when I assign this to a variable or put it into a cell it only returns part of the URL. The site im trying to access has a # in the URL (Sorry it is a confidential website so I cant put it here but it is in the format www.something.com/somethingelse/#thisBitWontDisplay.....). Everything after the # wont appear. I know that `IE.LocationURL` is working as when I look in the local variable bit in VBA editor it shows me that the value of `IE.LocationURL` is the correct URL but that's it, I can access the rest of the URL. I have tried to format the output of `IE.LocationURL` and also the variable but it wont work. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for posting the question and then answering it 10 minutes later but I found the solution. It was my mistake i was not giving IE enough time to load the webpage. I put in a 5 second delay and it worked. Hope this helps anybody in the future